# A strange output in welcome message

Tags: scp, sftp, motd

Days ago I found I cannot connect my server via `sftp`. Then I found that there is a dot in the welcome message when I login via `ssh`.

```
 .Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-72-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

 * Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is out, raising the bar on performance, security,
   and optimisation for Intel, AMD, Nvidia, ARM64 and Z15 as well as
   AWS, Azure and Google Cloud.

     https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-20-04-lts-arrives


31 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.

*** System restart required ***
```

There is a dot in front of "Welcome to ...". I am sure that this dot is not a part of motd. I try `ssh username@remote "echo hello"`,and get ".hello". I tried to find out where it comes from but failed, and I am new to Linux. Does anyone have any ideas about where does this dot come from?

Comment: What is output of `type echo` ?

Comment: @pLumo I got `echo is a shell builtin`

Comment: This likely comes from some output in the login shell's startup files. Are you able to have a look at your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profile` (or the equivalent files for whatever shell you use), or share them in the question?